# where is the basepath variable being set for the zend basePath view helper (maybe a factory)

Tags: zend-framework, zend-framework2, zend-view

Id like to see how the `base path view helper` sets up the base path variable inside the helper class.

This is an internal based questions, as I imagine its being done with a factory behind the scenes.

I needed to replicate it with a custom version but im hardcoding the base path currently: `You'll see that even though its extending the basepath viewhelper i cannot configure the basepath variable without this current solution of hardcoding it`

```
class PlutoBasePath extends \Zend\View\Helper\BasePath
{

 public function __construct()
 {
    /**
     * @todo
     * @var Ambiguous $basePath
     */
    $this->basePath = Pluto::registry('prepend_location_url');  
 } 

 public function __invoke($file = null)
 {
        if (null === $this->basePath) {
            throw new Exception\RuntimeException('No base path provided');
        }

        if (null !== $file) {           
            \Pluto\Stdlib\FilesystemUtils::sanitizeFilePaths($file);
            \Pluto\Stdlib\FilesystemUtils::trimLeadingPath($file);                  
        }                       
        return $this->basePath.$file;
 }
}
```

Id rather use a factory but I dont know how to access the base path set logic **WHICH SETS UP THE FACTORY BASE PATH FOR THE base path view helper** `to setup the custom base path correctly`

**How is it possible for me to  see the factory creation of the base path view helper is my base question**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I seem to have found where the basepath is set, here `Zend\Mvc\Service\ViewHelperManagerFactory::createBasePathHelperFactory()`.

```
private function createBasePathHelperFactory(ContainerInterface $services)
    {
        return function () use ($services) {
            $config = $services->has('config') ? $services->get('config') : [];
            $helper = new ViewHelper\BasePath;

            if (Console::isConsole()
                && isset($config['view_manager']['base_path_console'])
            ) {
                $helper->setBasePath($config['view_manager']['base_path_console']);
                return $helper;
            }

            if (isset($config['view_manager']) && isset($config['view_manager']['base_path'])) {
                $helper->setBasePath($config['view_manager']['base_path']);
                return $helper;
            }

            $request = $services->get('Request');

            if (is_callable([$request, 'getBasePath'])) {
                $helper->setBasePath($request->getBasePath());
            }

            return $helper;
        };
    }
```

I hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Here is a piece of code that I use in my application and that should answer your question (to be adapted according to the schema of your project)

```
    use Zend\View\Renderer\PhpRenderer;
    use Zend\View\Resolver;
    ...
    $stack = new Resolver\TemplatePathStack(
        [
            'script_paths' => [
                __DIR__ . '/../../../view'
            ]
        ]);
    $resolver = new Resolver\AggregateResolver();
    $resolver->attach($stack);
    $renderer = new PhpRenderer();
    $renderer->setResolver($resolver)
        ->plugin('basePath')
        ->setBasePath('/');
```